# process allocated memory blocks from kernel

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

i need to have reliable measurement of allocated memory in a linux process. I've been looking into [mallinfo](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Statistics-of-Malloc.html) but i've read that [it is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564752/examining-c-c-heap-memory-statistics-in-gdb). What is the state of the art alternative for this sort of statistics?

basically i'm interested in at least two numbers:

- number (and size) of allocated memory blocks/pages from the kernel by any `malloc` or whatever implementation uses the C library of choice
- (optional but still important) number of allocated memory by userspace code (via `malloc`, `new`, etc.) minus the deallocated memory by it (via `free`, `delete`, etc.)

one possibility i have is to [override malloc calls with LD_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083337/overriding-malloc-using-the-ld-preload-mechanism#), but it might introduce an unwanted overhead at runtime, also it might not interact properly with other libraries i'm using that also rely on LD_PRELOAD aop-ness.

another possibility i've read is with [rusage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669438/how-to-get-memory-usage-at-run-time-in-c).

To be clear, this is **NOT** for debugging purposes, the memory usage is intrinsic feature of the application (similar to Mathematica or Matlab that display the amount of memory used, only that more precise at the block-level)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/proc/PID/status` contains a few useful pieces of information (try running `cat /proc/$$/status` for example).

`VmPeak` is the largest your process's virtual memory space ever became during its execution.  This includes all pages mapped into your process, including executable pages, mmap'ed files, stack, and heap.

`VmSize` is the current size of your process's virtual memory space.

`VmRSS` is the Resident Set Size of your process; i.e., how much of it is taking up physical RAM right now.  (A typical process will have lots of stuff mapped that it never uses, like most of the C library.  If no processes need a page, eventually it will be evicted and become non-resident.  RSS measures the pages that remain resident and are mapped into your process.)

`VmHWM` is the High Water Mark of `VmRSS`; i.e. the highest that number has been during the lifetime of the process.

`VmData` is the size of your process's "data" segment; i.e., roughly its heap usage.  Note that small blocks on which you have done `malloc` and then `free` will still be in use from the kernel's point of view; large blocks will actually be returned to the kernel when freed.  (If memory serves, "large" means greater than 128k for current glibc.)  This is probably the closest to what you are looking for.

These measurements are probably better than trying to track malloc and free, since they indicate what is "really going on" from a system-wide point of view.  Just because you have called `free()` on some memory, that does not mean it has been returned to the system for other processes to use.

Answer (score 4):

For this purpose - a "memory usage" introspection feature within an application - the most appropriate interface is `malloc_hook(3)`.  These are GNU extensions that allow you to hook every `malloc()`, `realloc()` and `free()` call, maintaining your statistics.

To see how much memory is mapped by your application from the kernel's point of view, you can read and collate the information in the `/proc/self/smaps` pseudofile.  This also lets you see how much of each allocation is resident, swapped, shared/private, clean/dirty etc.