# How to check stack and heap usage with C on Linux?

Tags: c, stack

Is there any way to retrieve the stack and heap usage in C on Linux?

I want to know the amount of memory taken specifically by stack/heap.

Comment: `valgrind` will tell you about heap usage (i.e. all calls to `malloc()` etc.) You'll need some sort of stack profiler to get information about the stack usage, though it's less clear what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: maybe you're looking for ["Examining C/C++ Heap memory statistics in gdb"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564752/examining-c-c-heap-memory-statistics-in-gdb)

Answer (score 5):

If you know the pid (e.g. 1234) of the process, you could use the `pmap 1234` command, which print the memory map. You can also read the `/proc/1234/maps` file (actually, a textual *pseudo-file* because it does not exist on disk; its content is lazily synthesized by the kernel). Read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) man page. It is Linux specific, but inspired by [`/proc` file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) on other Unix systems.

<sup>(you'll better open, read, then close that pseudo-file quickly; don't keep a file descriptor on it open for many seconds; it is more a "pipe"-like thing, since you need to read it sequentially; it is a pseudo-file without actual disk I/O involved)</sup>

And from inside your program, you could read the `/proc/self/maps` file. Try the 
 `cat /proc/self/maps` command in a terminal to see the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) map of the [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) running that `cat` command, and `cat /proc/$$/maps` to see the map of your current shell.

All this give you the memory map of a process, and it contains the various memory segments used by it (notably space for stack, for heap, and for various dynamic libraries).

You can also use the `getrusage` system call.

Notice also that with multi-threading, each [thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) of a process has its own [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

You could also parse the `/proc/$pid/statm` or `/proc/self/statm` pseudo-file, or the `/proc/$pid/status` or `/proc/self/status` one.

But see also [Linux Ate my RAM](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/) for some hints.

Consider using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (at least on Linux) to debug [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).