# Where are global variables located in the activation record for C?

Tags: c, global-variables, activation-record

In C, each function has an activation record which is allocated on  a stack frame. Local variables are allocated in their own function's activation record. So, what is the case with global variables? Where are they allocated?

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int a;

    void v()
    {a= 2;
    int b;
    b++;
    }

    main()
    {
    int f;
    printf("\n%d",a);
    v();
    }


-----Activation record----

-------------------
-------------------
activation record for main
-------------------
int f
-------------------
-------------------
activation record of v
--------------------
int a
--------------------
int b
--------------------
---------------
```

---

Where is variable `x` stored according to the activation record logic?

Comment: Global variables are not stored in the "activation record" (or "stack frame"). That is where automatic (or local) variables are stored. However, the C standard does not  mandate where variables are stored, only how they should function. It does not mention the terms "stack", "heap" or "activation".

Comment: In general global variables are stored in what is called data segment. It is a part of the memory which is mapped to variables during the linking process and it does not change during the run time. It is allocated in the actual memory on load time.

Answer (score 2):

> In C each function has an activation record which is allocated on a stack frame.

Nope. However, this is how it is usually solved by the compiler. At least if you have not activated any optimizations.

Firstly, the C standard does not say anything about a stack at all. So an answer to this will be about how it's usually solved in practice.

And usually they are in the data segment or bss segment. A typical layout looks like this:

```
Stack - Grows down towards the heap. Used for local variables.
-----
...
...
...
----
Heap - Grows up towards the stack. Used for dynamically allocated memory.
----
BSS - Uninitialized data. Used for uninitialized global and static variables.
----
Data - Initialized data. 
----
Text - Runnable code
```

Answer (score 1):

> In C each function has an activation record which is allocated on a stack frame.

**Wrong**, an [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) might not do that (and `gcc -O3 -flto` won't, on Linux / x86-64 with a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)). It will [inline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) some functions. Some locals are only kept in some [processor registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) (so have no memory location). Read about [register allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation), e.g. in the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) or some other textbook about compilers. Be aware of [automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable). Be also aware that you don't even need a computer to run a C program (a good way of teaching C is to have the classroom play being a computer; and you could run a C program on paper with a pencil).

The globals are usually not in practice on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (which hold call frames or activation records). They might sit in the [data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) (and could be optimized out entirely).

The C11 specification does not require any call stack. Check by reading [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Some implementations don't use any call stack (or activation records). Be aware of the [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) calling your `main`.

Read [linkers and loaders](https://www.iecc.com/linker/) for more. Read also a [textbook about operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

On Linux, try `cat /proc/self/maps` to understand the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of the [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) running that `cat` command; see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Look into the assembler code generated by `gcc -O2 -fverbose-asm -S`, using Linux. Read about [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7902058/841108).

On Linux, play with [nm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html), [readelf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html), [objdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) on your [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) or [object file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_code) (in [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format).